# Unknown host exception nexus.codehaus.org in maven build

Tags: maven

I am building the Apache Ignite project  http://github.com/apache/ignite .

One of the maven pom.xml refers to the `codehaus` exec-maven-plugin .  Note that *codehaus is now defunct as a company*.

Is there something in the plugin itself that links to the http://nexus.codehaus.org repository?  Consider the error message from running

```
 mvn clean package
```

on that project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-
plugin:1.3.2:java (default) on project ignite-core: Execution 
default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java failed:
 Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact
 org.apache.ignite:ignite-tools:jar:1.4.1-SNAPSHOT from/to 
codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/):
 nexus.codehaus.org: Unknown host nexus.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the snippet of pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>schema-import/src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Note: I am not all certain that the error were due to the codehaus mojo plugin. It is simply here noted given that were the only reference to codehaus in the project.

Comment: I have this same problem with the `exec-maven-plugin` - you are not crazy. I have a `<dependency>` in the exec-maven-plugin and it keeps trying to download it from snapshots.repository.codehaus.org. Guess what, it can't find it there. I have searched all through the plugin code (and mine), nothing refers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question years after the fact but I actually have an answer. Use a newer (most recent perhaps) version of the plugin.

The old versions of the plugins are hard-coded to look for the http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org. If you upgrade to a new version you should be ok.

Works for `build-helper-maven-plugin` and for `exec-maven-plugin`.

**Old:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</plugin>
```

**New:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: We need a `deep spelunker` badge for this

Answer (score 3):

The Codehaus has shutdown it's doors. The new home of the plugins is: http://www.mojohaus.org/. And in particular for the [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). The source code can be found: https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/. Apart from that a project referencing a SNAPSHOT repository is simply wrong. Is the codehaus repository referenced in your pom or in the ignite project?

Comment: The pom.xml snippet is directly from the Ignite project.  I already mentioned in the OP that Codehaus has shutdown: so the question is: what to do with the existing pom.xml for migration. I am perusing the source now to see if can shed some light.

Comment: Codehaus did indeed shut its doors. Which makes it really annoying that their maven plugin keeps trying to download poms from their now-defunct repository. There is a bug in the code somewhere, I do not know where. The plugin tries to download files from codehaus.org's repo. It makes the internet sad.

Comment: The problem is what i addressed in my answer - you need to use the latest version that have come from mojohaus. If you are using an old version of the plugin (when it was called codehaus), something in the plugin will add codehaus.org as a repository and break your build. Maven will timeout trying to download ALL your dependencies from codehaus.org, not just the plugin. The OP's essentially just needed to update the version of the plugin.